# bootstrap 3 navigation bar background repeat

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

This is what I would like to have:

[image: goal]

i.e., a bootstrap navigation bar that takes up 100% of the screen width, and, on the right side has that particular design: black / red.

As of now, this is what I have in terms of structure:

[image: structure]

I guess that I need to use this image:
[image: red]
as well as repeat this one:
[image]

But I'm unable to do it, as I can't find a proper structure or logic.
How should I do it?
Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Here's some sample code:
http://www.bootply.com/O0EdufR1Jx

Answer (score 2):

You can use an absolutely positioned container with a :before container styled like a triangle.  This isn't the cleanest but is a good starting point to work from.  Code could certainly be cleaned up.

http://www.bootply.com/soi5inhR2O

Give this a shot:

CSS

```
.container-bg {
   background-color:#ccc; 
}

.navbar .container {
     float: left;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: #222;
      padding: 0;
      position: relative;
}
.container>.navbar-header {
    width: 1170px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: none;
}
.navbar>.container .navbar-brand {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
}
#navbar {
     float: left;
     width: 100%;
     background-color: #fff;    
}
span.red-section {
     position: absolute;
     right: 0;
     top: 0;
     height: 50px;
     background-color: red;
     width: 25%;
}
span.red-section:before {
     content: '';
     border-right: 50px solid red;
     border-top: 50px solid transparent;
     position: absolute;
     left: -50px;
     top: 0;  
}
```

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img alt="" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16451566/stackoverflow/20150403/logo.jpg">
      </a>
      <span class="red-section"></span>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item 5</a></li> 

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container container-bg">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <p>some content here...</p>
      <p>some content here...</p>
      <p>some content here...</p>
      <p>some content here...</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Hi Matt, thaks for the suggestion!